# Fadein, Fadeout events together using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want fade in fade out event work separately for all the div but when my mouse enters first div it effect all other div.If I do not define demo and demo1 function separately then its working fine otherwise its working like this.I do not understand what is wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Fade Out Example</p><br>
<div class="fade" id="div1" style="background-color:red;width:100px; height:100px"> </div><br>
<div class="fade" id="div2" style="background-color:blue;width:100px; height:100px"> </div><br>
<div class="fade" id="div3" style="background-color:cyan;width:100px; height:100px"> </div>

</body>

    <script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#div1").bind("mouseenter",(demo));
    $("#div1").bind("mouseleave",(demo1));

        $("#div2").bind("mouseenter",(demo));
        $("#div2").bind("mouseleave",(demo1));

            $("#div3").bind("mouseenter",(demo));   
                $("#div3").bind("mouseleave",(demo1));
    });
function demo()
{
$("#div1").css("background-color","lightgreen").fadeOut();
$("#div2").fadeOut();
$("#div3").fadeOut();
}
function demo1(){
    $("#div1").css("background-color","red").fadeIn();
        $("#div2").fadeIn();
            $("#div3").fadeIn();
}
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: HTML inside `<script></script>` .. really? :)

Comment: that was by mistake while posting...:(

Comment: Your code says to fade out all 3 or fade in all 3. If thats not what you want then dont put it.

Comment: Ben-  how can I correct this???\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use fadeTo which will not remove the div element in your DOM; run it in code snippet

```js
    function demo(id)
    {
        if(id == 1){
            $("#div"+id).css("background-color","lightgreen").fadeTo('slow',0);
        }else if(id != 1){
            $("#div"+id).fadeTo('slow',0);
        }
    }
    function demo1(id){
        if(id == 1){
            $("#div"+id).css("background-color","red").fadeTo('slow',1);
        }else if(id != 1){
            $("#div"+id).fadeTo('slow',1);
        }
    }
```

```css
<style>
    .fade{display: block;}
</style>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Fade Out Example</p><br>
<div class="fade" id="div1" style="background-color:red;width:100px; height:100px" onmouseover="demo('1');" onmouseout="demo1('1')"> </div><br>
<div class="fade" id="div2" style="background-color:blue;width:100px; height:100px" onmouseover="demo('2');" onmouseout="demo1('2')"> </div><br>
<div class="fade" id="div3" style="background-color:cyan;width:100px; height:100px" onmouseover="demo('3');" onmouseout="demo1('3')"> </div>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you @Priyanka Maurya,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('div.fade').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).animate({
        opacity: '0.2'
    },1500);  
    });
    $('div.fade').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).animate({
        opacity: '1'
    },1500);
    });

});
```

Comment: Your require ment is " On mouse enter, that div only show with fadein and other div should fadeout  " correct?

Comment: yes...at once the effect should be only for one div..both fade in and fade out.

Comment: Okay, got it, The answer is modified. The answer which you have given is not appropriate, what you will you do if there are 100 divs. Hence the code should be generic like above.

Comment: I dont want css background red color to second and third divs. as I am trying to do in my question.

Answer (score 0):

@Harish's javascript is the correct solution but the issue you will continue to see is related to the display property. `fadeOut()` sets an elements `display` value to none at the end of the animation, meaning that your blocks will reflow and mouse leaves the current block and enters the one proceeding it.

You will need to reserve the space so that the entire element does not collapse to get the effect you are looking for.

http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/#entry-longdesc

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<p>Fade Out Example</p><br>
<div class="fade" id="div1" style="background-color:red;width:100px; height:100px"> </div><br>
<div class="fade" id="div2" style="background-color:blue;width:100px; height:100px"> </div><br>
<div class="fade" id="div3" style="background-color:cyan;width:100px; height:100px"> </div>

</body>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#div1").click(demo());
    $("#div2").click(demo2());
    $("#div3").click(demo3());
    });

function demo()
{
$("#div1").mouseenter(function(){
        $("#div1").css("background-color","lightgreen").fadeOut();
    });
    $("#div1").mouseleave(function(){
$("#div1").css("background-color","red").fadeIn();
});
}
function demo2()
{
$("#div2").mouseenter(function(){
        $("#div2").fadeOut();
    });
    $("#div2").mouseleave(function(){
$("#div2").fadeIn();
});
}
function demo3()
{
$("#div3").mouseenter(function(){
        $("#div3").fadeOut();
    });
    $("#div3").mouseleave(function(){
$("#div3").fadeIn();
});
}

    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Inside you click event, you want mouseenter & mouseleave?

Comment: Without giving click event its not taking demo function...but without clicking also those function are getting executed.you just need to do mouse in and mouse out on the div..thats what I want..Tell if its possible without using click event.

Comment: The problem is, when you mouse enter the div is getting fade out and change to display none. Hence the below div is getting up. (i.e. filling the area of the top div.). Instead of that you can use css opacity.

Comment: yes that I know that 2nd div replaces 1st one. how can I use opacity? means how can 1st div holds its place and just hide itself and again be visible?